# Get average value of keys in a dictionary that are in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I want to get the average values for all "Jazz"-keys, however, I want to do it for each separate key within the nested dictionary.

```
def average_ratings(aDict) :
    for key in aDict :
        if "Jazz" in aDict:
            mySum = 0
            numNums = 0
            while value in aDict['Jazz'] :
                mySum = mySum + value
                numNums = numNums + 1
            jazzValue = mySum / numNums
            return jazzValue
        if "Rock" in aDict :
            summ = 0
            num = 0
            while value in aDict["Rock"] :
                summ = summ + 1
                num = num + 1
            rockValue = summ / num
            return rockValue
```

This is the dictionary I am passing through

```
{'Justin Trudeau': {'Hits': 4, 'Jazz': 3, 'Rock': 7, 'Reggae': 7, 'Dance': 7, 'Blues': 6, 'Rap': 4}, 'Bob Jones': {'EDM': 4, 'Dance': 3, 'Hits': 1, 'Rock': 3, 'Opera': 4, 'Funk': 3, 'Soul': 6, 'Metal': 8, 'Classical': 9}, 'Sam Frizzel': {'Rap': 7, 'Hits': 6, 'Soul': 2, 'EDM': 5, 'Pop': 3, 'Reggae': 3, 'Hip Hop': 5}, 'Captain Nemo': {'Dance': 4, 'Rock': 2, 'Classical': 10, 'World': 8, 'Jazz': 9, 'Hip Hop': 6, 'Soul': 4, 'Metal': 2}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [33]: a = {'Justin Trudeau': {'Hits': 4, 'Jazz': 3, 'Rock': 7, 'Reggae': 7, 'Dance': 7, 'Blues': 6, 'Rap': 4}, 'Bob
    ...:  Jones': {'EDM': 4, 'Dance': 3, 'Hits': 1, 'Rock': 3, 'Opera': 4, 'Funk': 3, 'Soul': 6, 'Metal': 8, 'Classica
    ...: l': 9},'Sam Frizzel': {'Rap': 7, 'Hits': 6, 'Soul': 2, 'EDM': 5, 'Pop': 3, 'Reggae': 3, 'Hip Hop': 5}}
    ...:

In [34]: jazz = [a[i].get('Jazz',0) for i in a if 'Jazz' in a[i]]

In [35]: print(sum(jazz)/len(jazz))
3.0
```

Update:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = {'Justin Trudeau': {'Hits': 4, 'Jazz': 3, 'Rock': 7, 'Reggae': 7, 'Dance': 7, 'Blues': 6, 'Rap': 4}, 'Bob Jones': {'EDM': 4, 'Dance': 3, 'Hits': 1, 'Rock': 3, 'Opera': 4, 'Funk': 3, 'Soul': 6, 'Metal': 8, 'Classical': 9}, 'Sam Frizzel': {'Rap': 7, 'Hits': 6, 'Soul': 2, 'EDM': 5, 'Pop': 3, 'Reggae': 3, 'Hip Hop': 5}, 'Captain Nemo': {'Dance': 4, 'Rock': 2, 'Classical': 10, 'World': 8, 'Jazz': 9, 'Hip Hop': 6, 'Soul': 4, 'Metal': 2}}

avgs = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in a.items():
    for i in v:
        avgs[i].append(v[i])
    
for k,v in avgs.items():
    print(f"Average of {k} is {sum(v)/len(v)}")
```

Output:

```
Average of Hits is 3.6666666666666665
Average of Jazz is 6.0
Average of Rock is 4.0
Average of Reggae is 5.0
Average of Dance is 4.666666666666667
Average of Blues is 6.0
Average of Rap is 5.5
Average of EDM is 4.5
Average of Opera is 4.0
Average of Funk is 3.0
Average of Soul is 4.0
Average of Metal is 5.0
Average of Classical is 9.5
Average of Pop is 3.0
Average of Hip Hop is 5.5
Average of World is 8.0
```

Comment: I think the correct output should be 3 (I could be wrong though..)

Comment: I assume OP is asking `mean`?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to get the total average of each genre for the total of all the people within the dictionary however there are some keys in some that are not in others.

Comment: What's the expected answer @user12344?

Comment: It varies each time, the dictionary I have created randomly generates a list of genres and values from a list I previously created. I just am trying to find a way to average each genre that is listed in the entire dictionary. So, in this case, the average would be 3. But for  Rock it would be 5.

Comment: @user12344 edit the question with exactly what you need

Comment: @user12344 Updated my answer.

Comment: Do you know how I could do these by using a dictionary defined outside the function?